# C++: How to capture the sound card's output?

Tags: audio, soundcard

I want to **capture the audio the sound card is playing** for my Java application.

Since there seems to be no way to do this using Java, I want to use C++, because I saw various posts that said that it was possible using C++. To implement the C++ code in Java I want to use JNI.

How could the C++ code to capture the audio look like?

Comment: It's not about language. It's about your audio service implementation. Start with explaining your OS, your audio server, etc.

Comment: The program should work on as many platforms as possible, so my own setup should not be important for this. I'm using Windows and the Realtek HD driver.

Comment: Whether it should or not, most likely it will require independent code paths for each major platform -- this is simply too system-specific.

Comment: For as simple as Realtek on Windows (Win10 for sure), just select "Stereo Mix" as a recording device. That way windows audio service allows dumping audio mixed from all playing sources in system. It might not exist on older windows, though. Similar stuff is available from Creative Sound Blaster ("What U Hear" device), and often it's not depending on windows version. But still, the whole idea of dumping played sound is too system-specific.

Comment: I know, that it won't work in all OS with only one code. I wanted to use .dll  / .so for Linux or the Mac equivalent. But I want to capture the sound only with the source code, not with other settings.

Comment: JUCE would be my go to on doing this in C++, but as is suggested in this [forum post](https://forum.juce.com/t/reading-audio-from-system-output/29224) it would be a case of routing audio to a software audio driver (e.g. Sound Flower) and then reading audio from that.